# Python - open gnome editor with Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, gedit

I want to use Python to start `gedit` (default gnome text editor) with a file already opened. I'm able to do so, but when called from Python `gedit` will always open an extra tab named "Untitled Document 1" with some sort of rotating refresh icon.

[image]

I started with

```
subprocess.call(["gedit", pathToFile])
```

but this blocked the main process, so I'm now using

```
Popen(["gedit", pathToFile])
```

Both commands result in the same unwanted behaviour.

This does **not** happen if I call gedit from the command line like this:

```
gedit pathToFile
```

Is there anything I'm missing from the Python side of the problem?

**Update**: From the accepted answer I came up with this as a working solution:

```
Popen(["gedit", pathToFile], stdin=open(os.devnull, 'r'))
```

Comment: Does adding `shell=True` help? Eg. `Popen(["gedit", pathToFile], shell=True)`

Comment: Hacking on same problem. Running the script with `strace` shows that there is endless loop of `gettimeofday()`  and `clock_gettime()`. Thousands of calls every second. Several millions over a short time. (If anyone want to look at what is actually going on). The solution provided does the trick though, so thumbs up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that it's trying to read from standard input or somesuch.

Try adding `stdin=open(os.devnull, 'r')` to the `Popen` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to replicate any problem with Popen running Python 2.7.3 on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.  Following is a partial transcript, with lines numbered for reference.  Before it printed line 3 or line 5, the python interpreter apparently blocked; when I exited from gedit, the 0's printed.  All of the gedit invocations started ok, and none of the ones with Popen blocked the interpreter.  Some of the files existed before they were gedit'ed, some did not.  Using `shell=True` with subprocess.call (an example not shown) made no difference, ie it blocked.

```
 1  >>> import subprocess
 2  >>> subprocess.call(['gedit','vv'], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
 3  0
 4  >>> subprocess.call(['gedit','vv'])
 5  0
 6  >>> pid = subprocess.Popen(['gedit','vv']).pid
 7  >>> pid
 8  3434
 9  >>> pid = subprocess.Popen(['gedit','uu']).pid
10  >>> pid
11  3442
12  >>> subprocess.Popen(['gedit','ww'])
13  <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1887c10>
14  >>> subprocess.Popen(['gedit','yy'])
15  <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1847c10>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - I also cannot reproduce the problem when trying from the command line. nneonneo's answer did the trick for my application.